# What fields does Latitude__c and Longitude__c must use?

Tags: custom-field, geolocation

Latitude_*c and Longitude*_c are 2 fields when i want to use google maps in my salesforce account. What data type do i need to use for two of them.
Can any one help me to integrate with salesforce to google maps.

Comment: I think this is maybe useful.It explain how it use Google Map https://blog.internetcreations.com/2012/09/creating-a-geolocation-trigger-in-salesforce-winter-13/#.WGPGHOgRXMI .

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [Geolocation field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm&language=en_US).  It is a compound field that consists of a Longitude and Latitude.

For example, if you create a custom Geolocation field called Location__c you will automatically be able to access the Longitude and Latitude in your code as follows:

`Location__Longitude__s` and `Location__Latitude__s`.

You can look at the [Geolocation Field Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm&language=en_US) for more information.